# Crosstab query in mysql using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in mysql, tbl_post & tbl_comment,

I require a crosstab query , based upon `tbl_post.post_id`, the result should be like

```
all elments of tbl_post + count of records form tbl_comment, where 
tbl_post.post_id == tbl_comment.post_id
```

e.g. Result should be like ::

```
post_id,title,content,tags,status,create_time,update_time,author_id,likes + count from tbl_comment
```

Please see the image.

I am new to sql just having academic knowledge , and couldn't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to join `tbl_post` to a subquery which counts the number of comments for each post.

```
SELECT t1.*,
       COALESCE(t2.post_count, 0) AS post_count
FROM tbl_post t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS post_count
    FROM tbl_comment
    GROUP BY post_id
) t2
    ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
```

If you want to create a view using the above query then you need to get a bit creative.  The following attempt will fail because the above query has a subquery in it:

```
CREATE VIEW PostCountView AS
SELECT t1.*,
       COALESCE(t2.post_count, 0) AS post_count
FROM tbl_post t1
...
```

Instead, you can create a view for the subquery, and then use that in a second view for the main query:

```
CREATE VIEW PostCountView AS
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS post_count
FROM tbl_comment
GROUP BY post_id

CREATE VIEW PostCountMainView AS
SELECT t1.*,
       COALESCE(t2.post_count, 0) AS post_count
FROM tbl_post t1
LEFT JOIN PostCountView t2
    ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
```

Comment: It works thanks, can you please tell me how to save this query as a view.

Comment: PhpMyadmin give error #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause.

Comment: @Raju I have updated my answer.  One solution is to use two views, one for the subquery.

Comment: Thanks, the view is created and I am successfully able to call it using PHP.

Comment: is this possible to add author_name from user_tbl in this main query, where tbl_post.author_id == tbl_user.author_id

Comment: @raju Sure, just do another join to the user table.

Comment: SELECT t1.*,
       COALESCE(t2.post_count, 0) AS post_count
FROM tbl_post t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS post_count
    FROM tbl_comment
    GROUP BY post_id
) t2
    ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
LEFT JOIN
(
 SELECT username
 FROM tbl_user
) t3
  ON t1.author_id = t3.user_id     NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.post_id,
       t1.title,
       t1.content,
       t1.tags,
       t1.status,
       t1.create_time,
       t1.updated_time,
       t1.author_id,
       t1.likes,
       count(t2.post_id)
from tbl_post t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_comment t2
    on t1.post_id = t2.post_id
group by t1.post_id;
```

Comment: This query has a serious problem, namely that it is selecting non aggregate columns while using `GROUP BY` only on the `post_id`.  This query would not even run on some versions of MySQL, or really any other database.